# Connecting to local virtual machine

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, virtual-machine

I suspect this has an easy solution I'm overlooking, probably to do with the client or how this is set up.
Anyways, I'm trying to set up a simple Echo server/client to understand the basics of socket programming.  I have a virtual machine running Linux Mint, and the host is running Windows 10.  The virtual machine I am setting to run the server c code, and the Windows will be running the client.

I started off making the server code

```
//Echo Server for UNIX:  Using socket programming in C, a client sends a string
//to this server, and the server responds with the same string sent back to the client

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char stringBuffer[50]; //string buffer for reading incoming and resending
    int listener, communicator, c; //store values returned by socket system call 

    if((listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) //creates a new socket
        puts("Could not create socket");
    puts("Socket Created");

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, client; //structure from <netinet/in.h> for address of server
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //addressing scheme set to IP
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(8888); //server listens to port 5000
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //symbolic constant of server IP address

    //binds the socket to the address of the current host and port# the server will run on
    if (bind(listener, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){
        puts("Bind failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Bind Successful");

    listen(listener, 5); //listens for up to 5 connections at a time
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((communicator = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&c ))<0)
        puts("accept failed");
    puts("Connection Accepted");
    //wait until someone wants to connect, then whatever is sent can be read from communicator, which can then be sent back

    while(1){
        bzero(stringBuffer, 50); //sets buffer to 0
        read(communicator, stringBuffer, 50); //reads from communicator into buffer
        write(communicator, stringBuffer, strlen(stringBuffer)+1); //returns back
    }
    return 0;
}
```

after that I tested it out by opening another terminal in the guest machine and typed "telnet localhost 8888" and input whatever strings I wanted.

This test worked so now, onto my Windows machine to create the client side of the socket programming:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    WSADATA wsadata; //variable for using sockets in windows
    SOCKET sock; //socket variable for network commands
    char sendString[50], recieveString[50]; //variables for sending and recieving messages to/from server

    //check if WSA initialises correctly
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsadata) != 0)
        printf("Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());

     //creates new socket and saves into sock
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        printf("Could not create socket: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    printf("Socket created\n");

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //sets the IP address to the same machine as the server
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //addressing scheme set to TCP/IP
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(8888); //server address is on port 8888

    //connects to device with specifications from servAddr
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0) {
        printf("Connection Error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Connection Accepted\n");

    while(1){
        fgets(sendString, 50, stdin); //uses stdin to get input to put into sendString
        //sends sendString to server using sock's properties
        if (send(sock, sendString, strlen(sendString) + 1, 0) < 0); {
            printf("Send Failed");
            return 0;
        }

        //reads from server into recieveString
        if ((recv(sock, recieveString, 50, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("Recieve Failed");
        printf("%s", recieveString); //prints out recieveString
    }
}
```

Now, with the server still running, when I try out the client-side, I get the response "Connection Error" (from line 35).  Having looked at both Unix and WinSock examples, I'm unsure as to why I would be failing the connection.  I suspect it might have something to do with a windows to linux VM but I'm not sure.

---UPDATE---
Having updated the accidental semicolon and added the WSAGetLastError, it's showing an error code of 10061;  This translates to 
"Connection refused.
No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running."

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after if-statement? line 34

Comment: `c` ought to be `socklen_t` *not* `int`!

Comment: Your *are* running server and client on the same box, aren't you?

Comment: @alk where are you talking about? and yes, windows10 with vmware linux mint on the same machine (my only computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[after the 3rd edit:]

Sry, just re-read your question. The important thing is here:

> The virtual machine I am setting to run the server c code, and the Windows will be running the client.

127.0.0.1 is an address always *only local* to an IP enabled box. So you your server is listening on the interface 127.0.0.1 local to the Linux VM and the client tries to connect to 127.0.0.0 local to the Windows box. Those two interfaces are *not* the same. The result is the obvious, namely the client does not find anything to connect to.

127.0.0.1 (the so called "*IPv4 local loopback interfac*e") can only be used for connections *local* to exactly *one* box.

Comment: okay that answers why, the question will be what IP do I use for that then?

Comment: The, err, IP of the server host?

Comment: namely speaking, I've also tried using INADDR_ANY for the server, but which IP for the client to send to? --Edit: okay, so do they really see each other as completely different things on a network? I'm not sure how IP addresses really work for guest machines, sorry

Comment: You will have to find out the IP address of the server host. Nobody can do that for you. The server program should certainly bind itself to INADDR_ANY, but that's only half the solution.

Comment: The linux command: `ip addr show` shows the available ip addresses.

Comment: @RELENTLESS00G: To identity all IP-interfaces existing on a Window box run `ipconfig` from a `cmd`-window. If the VM is up at least one of those interfaces listed should be connected to the VM. An exception to this might be that the VM uses of a bridged interface only. If so reconfigure the VM to also provide an interface local to the hosting box (Windows here). If unsure with this it might be worth posting another question.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0); {
    printf("Connection Error");
    return 1;
}
```

This is just a trivial syntax mistake. You are entering the block unconditionally. Remove the first semicolon.

However there is a much more important point to be made. When you get an error from a system call such as `connect()`, you must *print the error*. Not just some message of your own devising. Otherwise you don't know whether you simply have a bug, or a temporary problem, or a long-lasting problem, or a permanent problem.

Change the `printf()` to:

```
printf("Connect error %s\n", WSAGetLastError());
```

*and then* don't *continue as though the error didn't happen.*

Note that this applies to *all* system calls, specifically including `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `connect()`, `accept()`, `recv()`, `send()`, and friends.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the semicolon, but it really wasn't the problem.  No idea why I forgot the WSAGetLastError() on that line but none of the other ones, thank you for pointing that out.  I have updated with the current error code and the translation.

Comment: It really *was* the problem. The problem now is WSAECONNREFUSED, which merely means there was nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: It didn't work before I made the conditional statements to see where it was going wrong; it was A problem, but only introduced while I was checking where the problem was.  Now the question is, why is that error coming up? In my server there is a listener at that IP:Port

Comment: Really. Can you Telnet to it? From this client host?